# How to refer my friend for a vacancy in my office?

Tags: software-industry, recruitment, references

My company at present is looking new IT recruiters. My close friend's girlfriend has just completed her Graduation and looking for a job. I really want to help her out and for that, I need to forward her CV to our HR Manager. Now, from the very beginning day, I and the HR Manager had a cold war, and it's still there. Now, if she comes for the interview without my reference, the chances of getting her selected is pretty low, as my company is looking for candidates with some experience. How to refer her?

Comment: If company policy tells you to forward her CV to your HR manager to refer her, then that's what you should do. Any attempt to circumvent that will likely backfire. This seems to be more a question of how to make peace with someone, or whether your HR manager would let your issues interfere with their job, because how you refer her is unlikely to matter if they'd do that, but we can't really tell you either of those things.

Comment: Does your company have a referral program? All companies I've worked in have had such.

Answer (score 2):

Find out whether your company has an official process for referring candidates. If so, follow it. If not, hand the CV to your manager/supervisor and let them handle it.

If you are determined to hand deliver her CV to the HR manager you might try something like this: *"Whatever disagreements you and I might have between us, this person would be good for our company and I think it would be worth it to consider her."* (Of course, you have to really believe it if you're going to say it.)

Comment: This could also be as easy as an email to the hiring manager with the resume of your friend.